# Haskell: I/O and Returning From a Function

Tags: haskell, types, io, monads

Please bear with me as I am very new to functional programming and Haskell.  I am attempting to write a function in Haskell that takes a list of Integers, prints the head of said list, and then returns the tail of the list.  The function needs to be of type [Integer] -> [Integer].  To give a bit of context, I am writing an interpreter and this function is called when its respective command is looked up in an associative list (key is the command, value is the function).

Here is the code I have written:

```
dot (x:xs) = do print x
      return xs
```

The compiler gives the following error message:

```
forth.hs:12:1:
Couldn't match expected type `[a]' against inferred type `IO [a]'
  Expected type: ([Char], [a] -> [a])
  Inferred type: ([Char], [a] -> IO [a])
In the expression: (".", dot)
```

I suspect that the call to print in the dot function is what is causing the inferred type to be IO [a].  Is there any way that I can ignore the return type of print, as all I need to return is the tail of the list being passed into dot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No. This is Haskell, not C - `return` isn't a reserved word, and `do`-blocks don't need to be terminated with a `while`-statement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In most functional languages, this would work.  However, Haskell is a *pure* functional language.  You are not allowed to do IO in functions, so the function can either be

1. `[Int] -> [Int]` without performing any IO or
2. `[Int] -> IO [Int]` with IO

The type of `dot` as inferred by the compiler is `dot :: (Show t) => [t] -> IO [t]` but you can declare it to be `[Int] -> IO [Int]`:

`dot :: [Int] -> IO [Int]`

See IO monad: http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/io.html

---

I haven't mentioned `System.IO.Unsafe.unsafePerformIO` that should be used with great care and with a firm understanding of its consequences.

Comment: The [`Debug.Trace`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Debug-Trace.html) module may be used to print things as well.

Answer (score 9):

As you may already know, Haskell is a "pure" functional programming language. For this reason, side-effects (such as printing a value on the screen) are not incidental as they are in more mainstream languages. This fact gives Haskell many nice properties, but you would be forgiven for not caring about this when all you're doing is trying to print a value to the screen.

Because the language has no direct facility for causing side-effects, the strategy is that functions may produce one or more "IO action" values. An IO action encapsulates some side effect (printing to the console, writing to a file, etc.) along with possibly producing a value. Your `dot` function is producing just such an action. The problem you now have is that you need something that will be able to cause the IO side-effect, as well as unwrapping the value and possibly passing it back into your program.

Without resorting to hacks, this means that you need to get your IO action(s) back up to the `main` function. Practically speaking, this means that everything between `main` and `dot` has to be in the "IO Monad". What happens in the "IO Monad" stays in the "IO Monad" so to speak.

**EDIT**

Here's about the simplest example I could imagine for using your `dot` function in a valid Haskell program:

```
module Main where

main :: IO ()
main =
    do
        let xs = [2,3,4]
        xr <- dot xs
        xrr <- dot xr
        return ()

dot (x:xs) =
    do
        print x
        return xs
```

Answer (score 8):

No, either your function causes side effects (aka IO, in this case printing on the screen), or it doesn't. `print` does IO and therefore returns something in `IO` and this can not be undone.

And it would be a bad thing if the compiler could be tricked into forgetting about the `IO`. For example if your `[Integer] -> [Integer]` function is called several times in your program with the same parameters (like `[]` for example), the compiler might perfectly well just execute the function only once and use the result of that in all the places where the function got "called". Your "hidden" print would only be executed once even though you called the function in several places.

But the type system protects you and makes sure that all function that use `IO`, even if only indirectly, have an `IO` type to reflect this. If you want a pure function you cannot use `print` in it.