# return CalendarTime value

Tags: date, haskell, time

User gives: year, month, day, hour and minute and I would like to return CalendarTime value using these values. How can I do that - because I have error: 'Couldn't match expected type IO CalendarTime against inferred type Int'. What is wrong in function getDateTime ?

Proposition: all values are correct, for example month is from range 1 - 12 etc - I deleted validation from below code because otherwise code would be too long.

```
isInteger i = not (null i) && all isDigit i

getInteger :: String -> IO Int
getInteger q = do
    putStr q;
    i <- getLine
    if isInteger i == False then do
            putStrLn "Bad number"
            getInt q
        else return (read i)

getDateTime :: String -> IO CalendarTime
getDateTime question = do
    putStr question;
    year <- getInteger "Year: "
    month <- getInteger "Month: "
    day <- getInteger "Day: "
    hour <- getInteger "Hour: "
    minute <- getInteger "Minute: "
    return CalendarTime(year month day hour minute 0)
```

Comment: Style point: don't say "if foo == False then...."; say "if not foo then....".  In this case it would be "if not $ isInteger i then..."

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4056867 .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line

```
return CalendarTime(year month day hour minute 0)
```

is read by the compiler as

```
return CalendarTime (year month day hour minute 0)
```

So it's not a call to `CalendarTime`. Instead you're feeding `CalendarTime` and `(year month day hour minute 0)` as arguments return. This is nonsense as `return` only takes a single argument and `year`is not a function. You probably meant

```
return (CalendarTime year month day hour minute 0)
```

though this still doesn't work since `CalendarTime` requires more arguments than that. (Assuming we're talking about the one in `System.Time` since you didn't specify the imports).

You probably want

```
return $ CalendarTime { ctYear = year
                      , ctMonth = toEnum (month-1)
                      , ctDay = day
                      , ctHour = hour
                      , ctMinute = minute
                      , ctSec = 0 })
```

This leaves the missing fields undefined, see [the relevant section in Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/systems-programming-in-haskell.html#system.calendartime) for more information.

You also misspelled `getInteger` as `getInt` in the recursive call in the first function, but I'm assuming that's a result of your cleanup of the validation code.

Comment: thx very much - your solution gives me warning so I have added and now is ok - thx: , ctPicosec = 0
                      , ctWDay = Monday
                      , ctYDay = 0
                      , ctTZName = ""
                      , ctTZ = 0
                      , ctIsDST = False

Answer (score 1):

You don't say exactly which line gives the error, but I'm guessing the problem is:

```
return CalendarTime(year month day hour minute 0)
```

In Haskell, parentheses are used only for grouping. Function application is implicit by writing one term after the other. `return` should be applied to the `CalendarTime` value, so you probably wanted this instead:

```
return (CalendarTime year month day hour minute 0)
```

Although this would be more idiomatic:

```
return $ CalendarTime year month day hour minute 0
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use the constructor `CalendarTime` like a function from other language styles.

```
return (CalendarTime year month day hour minute 0)
```