# Haskell Implement an IO code

Tags: haskell

Im trying to implement an IO code with this concept:

- Asking the user for the film title
- checks if the film exist, if it does not it returns to the main menu
- if it does the programs asks the user for the rating
- it checks if its a valid integer, if it does
- the program checks  if the user has already voted for this film
- if he does then asks if he want to modify the rating
- if the user's input its not equal to "y" then the program should return to the main menu
- if the user type "y" then the database should be updated with the current ratting.

I tried this :

```
if input /= "y"
    then do return (username, database)
    else do putStrLn "Your vote will be modified."
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `()'
                with actual type `(String, Database)'
    In the first argument of `return', namely `(username, database)'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: return (username, database)
    In the expression: do { return (username, database) }
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

if run it like that:

```
if input /= "y"
    then do return (username, database)
    else do putStrLn "Your vote will be modified."
```

even if the user's input not equals to "y" the database will be updated.
I can't figure out where's the problem with return (username, database)

The code is:

```
options 7 (username, database) = do
    putStrLn "******************"
    putStrLn "   Rate a film    "
    putStrLn "******************"
    putStrLn ""
    putStr "Enter the title of the film or nothing to return to the main menu: "
    title <- getLine
    if title == ""
        then return(username, database)
        else do
            let filmCheck = findFilm title database
            if filmCheck == []
                then do
                    putStrLn "That film does not exists."
                    return (username, database) 
                else do
                    putStr "Enter your rate: "
                    tempRate <- getLine
                    case reads tempRate :: [(Integer, String)] of
                         [(n, "")] -> do
                            let rate = read tempRate :: Int
                            let tempFilm = rateFilm username (username, rate) filmCheck
                            when (checkIfRated username tempFilm == True) $ do
                                putStrLn "You already voted for this film\n"
                                putStrLn "Do you want to modify your vote?\n"
                                putStrLn "Press y to modify or nothing to return to the main menu:"
                                input <- getLine
                                if input /= "y"
                                    then do return (username, database)
                                    else do putStrLn "Your vote will be modified."
                            let database = tempFilm:database
                            putStrLn "You rating has been  sumbited successfully!"
                            putStrLn (displayFilm tempFilm)
                            return (username, database)
                         _ -> do
                            putStrLn "The number you entered is invalid."
                            return (username, database)
```

Comment: Are you expecting `return (username, database)` to exit the function?  All it does is wrap a value in the monadic context, the code `f = do { return "hello"; return "world"; return 1; putStrLn "Returned 1"; return 2 }` will return `2` because that's the last statement to execute in that block.  The other `return`s are just normal function calls.

Comment: Another bug I spotted, `let database = tempFilm:database` will not work as you expect.  It does not rebind the `database` value to the new one.  Instead, you're defining a recursive binding for `database` which would expand to be the equivalent of `repeat tempFilm`.  Instead, you should do something like `let newDatabase = tempFilm : database`, then do `return (username, newDatabase)`.

Comment: Thats exactly What I'm trying to do. Instead of return how is possible to force haskell to exit the function? Is there any way?
And thanks for the spotted bug.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4056867 .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your indentation is wonky. Remember that indentation is significant in Haskell; if you get it wrong, you *change the meaning* of the code!

At first glance, I think the problem is here:

```
if input /= "y"
  then do return (username, database)
  else do putStrLn "Your vote iwll be modified."
```

The "do" keywords are actually redundant here. But much more importantly, `putStrLn` returns a `()`, whereas `return` clearly returns something else. There's your error.

As another aside, try breaking this into way, way smaller functions. This isn't *Java*...

Comment: I think the real problem is that `return` does not exit the function, it just wraps a monadic value.  My guess is that OP is assuming that `return` is a keyword as in many other languages and that it actually forces the function to exit with the given value, but in Haskell it's just a function for wrapping values up in a monad.

Comment: @bheklilr You may be correct. I saw several branches _end_ with a `return`, which looks legit. But that if-block right in the middle? That _does_ look kind of suspect, now that you mention it...

Comment: I managed to get the result I wanted to by simplifying my coding and using only less complex if statements. Thank you all!