# Haskell IO method that does nothing

Tags: haskell, io

Here is my code:

```
foo :: Int -> IO()
foo a 
   | a > 100 = putStr ""
   | otherwise = putStrLn "YES!!!"
```

The function should output "YES!!!" if it is less than 100 and output nothing if it is more than 100. Although the above works, is there a more formal way to return nothing other than printing an empty string. e.g.

```
foo :: Int -> IO()
foo a 
   | a > 100 = Nothing
   | otherwise = putStrLn "YES!!!"
```

Comment: I'm just revisiting Haskell after some years of pause, and this was the same train of thought I was following. This helps wrap my head around and be able to think in Haskell way (as opposed to, say, Python).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4056867 .

Answer (score 11):

```
foo :: Int -> IO ()
foo a 
   | a > 100 = return ()
   | otherwise = putStrLn "YES!!!"
```

Answer (score 6):

If you import `Control.Monad`, you'll have access to the `when` and `unless` functions, which have the types

```
when, unless :: Monad m => Bool -> m () -> m ()
```

And can be used in this case as

```
foo a = when (not $ a > 100) $ putStrLn "YES!!!"
```

Or the more preferred form

```
foo a = unless (a > 100) $ putStrLn "YES!!!"
```

The `unless` function is just defined in terms of `when` as:

```
unless b m = when (not b) m
```