# Haskell: difference between let x = fn(intStr); return x and return fn(inpStr)?

Tags: haskell, monads

In Haskell, I have a function

```
fn :: String -> Int
```

Then I try to use it in an IO monad

```
mn = do
     inpStr <- readFile "input.txt"
     return fn(inpStr)
```

**EDIT**: I am using GHCi, version 7.10.2

I got the error message

```
Couldn't match type ‘[Char] -> Integer’ with ‘IO b’
    Expected type: String -> IO b
      Actual type: String -> [Char] -> Integer
    Relevant bindings include mn :: IO b (bound at 01.hs:13:1)
    The function ‘return’ is applied to two arguments,
    but its type ‘([Char] -> Integer) -> String -> [Char] -> Integer’
    has only three
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: return fn (inpStr)
    In the expression:
      do { inpStr <- readFile "input.txt";
           return fn (inpStr) }
```

However, if I change my code to

```
mn = do
     inpStr <- readFile "input.txt"
     let x = fn(inpStr)
     return x
```

It works.

What is the difference between `let x = fn(intStr); return x` and `return fn(inpStr)`?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4056867 .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`return fn(inpStr)` is the same as `return fn insStr`. you probably want `return (fn insStr)`.

In Haskell there aren't parentheses for function application, juxtaposition is enough. Parentheses are used to group things.