# How does getLine work in haskell?

Tags: haskell, io, functional-programming, getline

Looking at the [definition of `getLine` in the Haskell Prelude](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/standard-prelude.html),
I get how the recursion works, where you keep asking for a character until you hit a newline and you buildup a list which you then return wrapped in an IO.

However my question is how do the `return` statements work in this case, specifically how does `return (c:....:return "")` work when you hit the base case. How do you cons a `return ""` on to a list?

Comment: Remember that strings are just lists of characters, so `""` is the same as `[] :: [Char]`, so cons'ing a character onto that empty list makes sense. Also, you don't directly cons it onto `return ""`. Notice the difference between `c : getLine` (which makes no sense) and `do { s <- getLine; return (c:s) }`

Comment: Note that the "" isn't being cons'ed to anything.

Comment: Where do you think that `return ""` is consed to anything?

Comment: @Alec ah thank you that makes a lot more sense!, i completely forgot that the <- binds the "" to the s. Just started learning I/O in haskell

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4056867 .

Answer (score 5):

`return` isn't a control structure like in most languages. It's a constructor for monadic values. Let's take a look at its type:

```
return :: Monad m => a -> m a
```

In this case, given a `String` value, it produces a `IO String` value.

The fact that `return` is the last expression evaluated in each branch of the `if` doesn't mean `return` ends execution; other expressions *could* occur after `return`. Consider this simple example from the list monad:

```
foo :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
foo x y = return x ++ return y
```

In the list monad, `return` simply creates a new single-item list containing its argument. Those two lists are then concatenated into the final result list returned by the function.

```
$ return 3 :: [Int]
[3]
$ foo 3 4
[3,4]
```

Answer (score 1):

`do`-notation is a syntax sugar.

```
do x <- e
   rest
```

is equivalent to

```
e >>= \x -> rest
```

where `>>=` is a `flatMap` or `bind` operation (it attaches a callback to `IO` container).

`flatMap :: IO a -> (a -> IO b) -> IO b` meaning is: given container of type `IO a` attach a callback of type `a -> IO b`, fired when container succeeds in its operation, and this produces a new container of type `IO b`

So

```
getLine =
    getChar >>= \c ->
        if c == '\n'
        then (return [])
        else getLine >>= \rest ->
             return (c : rest)
```

What is means? `getLine` immediately delegates execution to `getChar` `IO`-container, with a callback, which analyses the character passed to it. If its a newline, it does "`return ""`", which is a construction of `IO`-container, returning empty `String` immediately.
Otherwise, we call ourselves, grab the `rest` and `return` current `c`haracter attached to `rest`.

P.S.: `return` is used to turn a pure value into container, since `Monad` interface doesn't allow us to bind non-container-producing callbacks (there are very good reasons for this).