# IO Monad with expected input value

Tags: haskell

I´m very new in Haskell, but still I cannot figure how the do block works regarding the monads.

For instance Having this do block which I return Integer is consider `IO Integer`

```
getNumber :: IO Integer -- A IO monad of type Integer
getNumber = return 100
```

But for instance having a do block that return a Maybe User the type of do block is `Maybe User` But I was expecting `IO (Maybe User)`

```
persistUser :: IO (Maybe User)
persistUser = do return Just(User { userId = 100, userName = "Paul" })
```

Instead the code is not even compiling. And I cannot figure the error compile.

```
• Couldn't match type ‘a0 -> Maybe a0’ with ‘IO (Maybe User)’
  Expected type: User -> IO (Maybe User)
    Actual type: User -> a0 -> Maybe a0
• The function ‘return’ is applied to two arguments,
  but its type ‘(a0 -> Maybe a0) -> User -> a0 -> Maybe a0’
  has only three
  In a stmt of a 'do' block:
    return Just (User {userId = 100, userName = "Paul"})
  In the expression:
    do { return Just (User {userId = 100, userName = "Paul"}) }
```

It seems like is expecting a User as input, but even adding the signature

`User -> IO (Maybe User)` or `User IO (Maybe User)` does not work.

Maybe I misuderstood something in the documentation. Some clarification about this it would be great!!

Regards.

Comment: Note the error hint: "The function ‘return’ is applied to two arguments". You are calling `return` with arguments 1) `Just` and 2) `User{...}`. This is not what you want.

Comment: As an aside, I find "The function `return` is applied to two arguments, but its type has only three" pretty funny. I wonder what the error-message logic is that lets that happen.

Comment: @DanielWagner It looks like the idea is that if the number of arguments is fixed (eg, `fst head [x]`), a reasonable error appears. But since `return` is polymorphic, `return f x` "could" have the right number of arguments, so we sneak by the "are there too many arguments" check. Then we land in code that assumes argument mismatch count means there are too few.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4056867 .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need more parentheses:

```
do return (Just(User { userId = 100, userName = "Paul" }))
```

Unlike many languages, `return` is not a special keyword in Haskell, but rather a library function, so one cannot omit parentheses around its argument as one could in other languages like C or Python.

Comment: Have no idea that return was a function. It has sense. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Daniel Wagner's answer, you can also use the `.` operator to compose `return` and `Just`:

```
getNumber = return . Just $ User { userId = 100, userName = "Paul" }
```

The `$` operator is a low-precedence function application operator that can be used to reduce parentheses; the above is equivalent to `return . Just (User { userId = 100, userName = "Paul" })`. (In fact, since `return = Just` in the `Maybe` instance, you could also write `return . return $ User { userId = 100, userName = "Paul" }`.)

In any case, `do` is unnecessary here, as you have only one "statement" after the keyword.

Comment: Thanks, and about the do block with one arg is just a POC to understand better how do block works.