# Why is the output of this Haskell function an IO String instead of a String

Tags: string, haskell, io, bind, monads

I'm learning Haskell through [learnyouahaskell.com](http://learnyouahaskell.com) and wanted to test some of the concepts before finishing the input/output module. I haven't been able to google or hoogle my way out of this question, though, even though it seems quite simple.

When I try to run the following code

```
getName = do
  name <- getLine
  return name
```

the output of `getName` becomes an element of type `IO String` instead of `String`, even though name is definitely a `String`

By reading the documentation and other StackVverflow's questions I couldn't figure out why is this happening when I declare `getName` as a function (when I use the bind <- operation directly on `main` there's no problem whatsoever).

Comment: Because `return` has type `Monad m => a -> m a`. You can not "unwrap" a value out of an `IO`. You could see an `IO` as a "recipe" to make a `String`, that is not the same as a string.

Comment: If you're coming from a background in imperative languages, be aware that `return` in Haskell is very different to `return` in those languages. `return` is a function in Haskell, in this case one with type `String -> IO String`.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot, guys. I completely overlooked how `return` works in this case.

Comment: If you just read further into LYAH you'll find all this explained (in the chapters on Monads). IO in Haskell, and do notation, always seems a bit "magical" when first encountered as a "this is how you do IO in Haskell", and these questions are perfectly natural. As I said, they get answered later on.

Comment: It's also worth noting that `do {x<-foo; return x}` is, by the [monad laws](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_monads#Monad_Laws), exactly the same as `foo` on its own. So all your code really does is define a new name `getName = getLine`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4056867 .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `return` *function* is not conceptually the same as what return does in languages like C++, Java and Python. [**`return :: Monad m => a -> m a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:return) takes an `a` (here a `String`), and produces an `m a` (here `IO a`).

The `do` notation is syntacticual sugar. If we desugar the statement, you wrote:

```
getName = getLine >>= (\name -> return name)
```

or cleaner:

```
getName = getLine >>= return
```

The bind function [**`(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-62--62--61-) thus has as first operand an `m a`, and as second a function `a -> m b`, and produces an `m b`. Since [**`getLine :: IO String`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:getLine) is an `IO String`, that thus means that `m` is the same as `IO`, and `a` is the same as `String`. The `return :: Monad m => a -> m a`, makes it clear that here `b` is the same as `a`.

Then what is `IO` here. A metaphor that is frequently used is the one of a *recipe*. In this metaphor an `IO a` is a set of instructions that when you follow these, you will get an `a`. But that does not mean that that recipe is an `a`.

`(>>=)` here basically says that, on the left hand I have a recipe to make `a`, on the right hand I have a function that converts that `a` into a recipe to make `b`, so we can construct a recipe to make `b` with these two.

People often ask how to unwrap an `a` out of an `IO a`, but conceptually it makes not much sense. You can not "unwrap" the cake out of a recipe to make a cake. You can follow the instructions to make a cake. Following instructions is something the `main` will eventually do. We thus can construct a (long) recipe the main will do. But we can not unwrap the values.

Strictly speaking there is a function [**`unsafePerformIO :: IO a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/System-IO-Unsafe.html#v:unsafePerformIO) that can do that. But it is *strongly* adviced not to use that. Functions in Haskell are supposed to be *pure* that means that for the same input, we always retrieve the same output. `getLine` itself is a pure, since it always produces the same recipe (`IO String`).